# CodeIgniter only loads default controller

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I've been crawling all over the internet and none of the solutions other people have used are working for me.  The problem is that the default controller is the only controller that will load.  There are many posts on here regarding this subject.  But I've tried all of them, including the main suggestion to try all five settings for the `$config['uri_protocol']`.  I've tried all five settings and none of them work.

I've also tried several different .htaccess settings and none of those help either.  Here are a couple I've tried.  The first is the official CI .htaccess from their website.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

and

```
#Standard CodeIgniter Rewrite
#-------------------------------------
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA] AddHandler cgi-script .pl
```

Still, no luck.  Can someone clue me into the correct combination of .htaccess and $config['uri_protocol'] settings.  All of the answers out there vary.  Is that because of different server configurations?

Answer (score 2):

I got it.  Finally.  Here is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /materials-library/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

And the `$config['uri_protocol']` is set to `REQUEST_URI`.